# Updating ui in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't seem to update the ui in one of my fragments, I'm not sure why.  I have a main activity which should send some json to the fragment and update the UI with the data from the JSON object.  I'm sending the json over successfully and I can log the data in the Fragment which I have sent over.  I am just not able to update the textbox value in the UI.

In my mainactivity

```
    MainPageFragment myFragment = new MainPageFragment();
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Create adapter that will return a fragment for each section of app
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

@Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject user) {


    //This seems to be all I need
    myFragment.grabJSON(user);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public  SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public  int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 1) {

                return new PreferenceFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings_preferances);
                    }
                };
            }

            else {
                return myFragment;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my MainFragment.java

```
public void grabJSON(JSONObject object){
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.usernameview);
            CharSequence val = usernameTextView.getText();
            Log.d("value", val.toString());

            usernameTextView.setText("NEW TEXT");//Set the Text
            val = usernameTextView.getText();
            Log.d("value", val.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

The fact that it sends the json is irrelevant, according to the log, my value of the textbox is changing but the actual UI is not changing.

I'm adding here the xml for the mainactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" ></FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

---

This has been updated with correct code, turns out I was defining the fragment twice

Thank you all,
Tom

Comment: Could you show the code where you're adding/removing the fragment?  Like for3st, it seems like there could be a problem if you're accidentally adding the fragment twice or somesuch so that **a** fragment instance updates, but not the one in the foreground.

Comment: I updated it with new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment is getting added twice.

It's added via the layout XML file, and then you do a fragment transaction to add it aw well.  Adding fragments via layout doesn't work as well as it should, so you should put in a placeholder view and then add the fragment via the fragment manager.  That should clear everything up.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, would I put the placeholder view in the mainactivity xml file, then place the fragment inside that?

Comment: @lostAstronaut Yep, exactly.  In the XML you put in an empty View or FrameLayout with appropriate `layout` attributes, and you then use its ID as the argument to the `FragmentTransaction.add(...)` call.

Comment: I updated it with what I thought you were saying, however now it seems i'm calling all my methods twice... and it is still crashing.  My only guesses is that I'm not setting up the fragment correctly at first and/or my frame placeholder is incorrect.

Comment: Oh you were right with the placeholder, I guess I was declaring my fragment at the top of my class and then again in the method... Fixed it, thanks for the placeholder help.  I'll update with my code which works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you dont add the fragment in the activity?

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MainPageFragment fragment = new MainPageFragment ();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a npe.